# Calculate full path from PWD and relative path in shell (substituting links)

Tags: shell, path

I need to calculate the full path to some file for a file given a relative path from the current directory.

`realpath` or `cygpath` (I'm on Cygwin, but this should apply to all *nix) does not work since I have a symbolic link in the path.

Is there an easy way to do "arithmetic" with path strings in bash/sh?

In essence I want to do

```
/home/me/dir + ../../you/folder = /home/you/folder
```

EDIT: bad question from me, asked for one thing and then for a problem detail in one solution.

I have
    /there
    /there/a
    /there/a/file
    /here/b -> symbolic link to ../there/a

With CWD=/here, I want the answer to the question "What is the canonical path to 'b/file'?" to be "/there/a/file".

Answer (score 0):

```
HERE=`pwd`
THERE=../../there/dir
while echo $THERE | grep '^\.\./' > /dev/null ; do 
  THERE=`echo $THERE | sed -e 's_^\.\./__'`
  HERE=`echo $HERE | sed -e 's_/[^/]\+$__'`
done
THERE=$HERE/$THERE
echo $THERE
```

Translations of regexes: at the beginning of the line `^`, match two literal dots followed by a slash `\.\./`

Match a slash `/` followed by one or more `\+` characters that are not slashes `[^/]` followed by the end of the line `$`

Comment: Note, it will break if $HERE ends in a slash.  To be sure, before the loop you could add: `THERE=\`echo $THERE | sed -e 's_/$__'\``

Comment: I've updated my answer because it had a bug.  In regex, `.` is a wildcard so `../` would match, for instance, `ab/`.  I changed the pattern to `\.\./` so it matches only a literal `.`

Answer (score 0):

Simple and efficient way to do it without any "arithmetic calculations" is to let the system to tell you the desired path. If your shell is Bash:

```
TGTFNAME="../../you/folder"
TGTPATH=$(cd "`dirname $TGTFNAME`" 2>/dev/null; pwd; cd - >/dev/null 2>&1;)
```

Comment: Although this works fine for the "path arithmetic", it does not give the path I want. (Edited the question to be more clear on the original problem.)

Comment: Thank You for the feedback @thoni56 , try use 'readlink' like this:
TGTFNAME="$(readlink \"../../you/folder\")" ; TGTPATH=...